# Historical Climate Data with High Resolution

Tags: data-request, climate

I am needing climate data in a high resolution (between 1Km-1000Km) by monthly or yearly since 2010. Where can I find this?

I can't find it in WorldClim neither in www.globalclimatemonitor.org

I want to relate climate variables with yields of agricultural crops in Peru by districts/provinces, so I need climate data in high resolution.

Comment: I assume nothing in http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/10154/sources-of-weather-data is helpful?