# Experimental data

Tags: data-request

I would be interested in some experimental data to play around with causality concepts. Ideally, this would be data where an accompanying paper is available as well. The data set could be relatively small, and should ideally come from a randomized experiment. It would be cool if there were some covariates. It would also be ideal if the experiment the dataset is based on would be fairly intuitive to understand for a layman in this area.

Can you think of a dataset, or sources for these types of datasets,  that at least satisfy some of these criteria?

Many thanks

Comment: Loads of weather data has some covariates between different things (temperature at two different places, or temperature and rainfall, etc.), also plenty of papers on google scholar. For data sources, see this question: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/10154/sources-of-weather-data/

Comment: Can this ever be experimental data?

Comment: Can you say more about what you mean by causality in this context? My background is in causal inference through epidemiology, but I want to make sure I'm on the same page. 

I think there are a few datasets covered in some of the books on causal inference around... what have you tried?