# Acquiring Global Data on Rainfall?

Tags: data-request

Does there exist a global dataset on rainfall (at least 0.5x0.5 degrees grid) already in .csv or similar format?

EDIT:

I have found this:
https://precip.gsfc.nasa.gov/

the precision is 1x1 log-lat grid. I check if it is enough for my case.

EDIT:
I see that asking about rainfall data is quite common. As soon as I write the code to properly open the binary files in the link above I will share it in order that order researcher will be able to easily use these data for whatever purpose they will to. The code will be R based.

Comment: have a look at this question: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/10154/11218

Comment: There seems to be available a Fortran program available on their [FTP-Server](ftp://meso.gsfc.nasa.gov/pub/1dd-v1.2/1dd_v1.2.software/) for this purpose (to import data from https://precip.gsfc.nasa.gov/). Maybe it is simple to reproduce that program in the language of your choice instead of writing your own program from the scratch. Additionally, the time series seems to have been discontinued in the end of 2015.

Comment: Thank you Daniel, I will try what you suggest. Unfortunately I do not know Fortran. However, given that the program should run without problems I will learn the basics and try out that option. (I need the information only up to 2013 included).

Answer (score 3):

[NOAA's ESRL : PSD : GPCC Precipitation Data Set](https://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/data/gridded/data.gpcc.html)

Provides three datasets:

First is the monitoring product for the period 2007 to present, based on quality-controlled data from 7,000 stations.

The second is the Full Data Product (V7)for the period 1901 to 2010, based on quality-controlled data from from 67,200 stations world-wide that feature record durations of 10 years or longer. This product contains the monthly totals on a regular grid with a spatial resolution of 0.5 x 0.5, 1.0 x 1.0, and 2.5 x 2.5 latitude by longitude. Precipitation anomalies at the stations are interpolated and then superimposed on the GPCC Climatology V2011 in the corresponding resolution.

The third is the first guess (1x1) which is most up-to-date but which has limited analyzed stations. We start this is 2012.

This data doesn't come as CSV, they files are of .nc, which I believe is NetCDF (Network Common Data Form).

Comment: Thanks Albert, I tried with the second option you suggested. However, the problem with the station collected data is that in some places there are not enough stations to get data at the 0.5x0.5 log-lat grid. I am actually looking for data on rain for Afghanistan for the period late 80s-2013. A better option would be to rely on data processed from satellite images. Any suggestions about those?

Comment: nasa, noaa, and a few other us government agencies have huge amounts of satellite open data....exactly for what you are looking for, i am not sure. but happy to help. i'll poke around and ping back.

Comment: Looking forward to it.