# Using NOAA api to get historical hourly temperature data

Tags: api, noaa

I've been attempting to use the NOAA api to get hourly temperature data for a specific location when given lat/lon coordinates. I can find the nearest weather station within an area of lat/lon coordinates using the station section of their api, but I need information from the ISD ([Integrated Surface Database](http://www7.ncdc.noaa.gov/CDO/cdopoemain.cmd?datasetabbv=DS3505&countryabbv=&georegionabbv=&resolution=40)) and have absolutely no idea how to see which station actually has access to this database, or if I'm even doing this the right way at all.

I'm so lost! This is what I basically need to do:

- receive input of latitude/longitude
- find nearest station/location that the [ISD](http://www7.ncdc.noaa.gov/CDO/cdopoemain.cmd?datasetabbv=DS3505&countryabbv=&georegionabbv=&resolution=40) has historical hourly temperature information about (last ~5 years or so)

and I really have no idea how to go about this using the NOAA api, or if I even *need* to use the NOAA api. Do I need to just download this information offline and then access it from a CSV or something similar? Any help or documentation you could provide would be very much appreciated. I've found very little documentation during this whole process and it's making it very frustrating.

Thanks so much!

**edit:** just wanted to note that I am not accessing the hourly data for any sort of profit, it's for an internal program that we're using to run simulations on our solar thermal panels

Comment: My kludge solution here would be to dl the data: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/10154/sources-of-weather-data/10155

Comment: https://github.com/ropensci/rnoaa ?