# time series for US weather

Tags: data-request, weather

is there a public resource for  weather time series (temperatures). my phone collects temperature by the hour but I wonder if weather stations store this information somewhere.

Data collection has improved so it I am only looking for recent years (and avoid too much work normalizing).

[image]

Comment: Have a look at this question: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/10154/sources-of-weather-data

Answer (score 0):

The most authoritative primary source for U.S. weather data is the [National Oceanic and Atmospheric Association](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/). NOAA is the primary agency that collects climate and weather data domestically.

Specifically, if you're looking for historical data, you may want to check out NOAA's [Climate at a Glance](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cag/) page.

Even more specifically targeted to your stated goal, you can use [IFTT](http://iftt.com) to set up a quick custom applet between [Weather Underground](http://wunderground.org) and [Google Sheets](http://sheets.google.com) that will log the weather forecast for you at sunrise each morning.

Best of luck!