# UK Wind Speed for QGIS

Tags: data-request, geospatial, weather, uses-of-open-data

I've looked at related questions but none seem to provide what I'm after.

I would like to hear if anyone knows open source data of annual wind speed (not direction) for the UK. The data can be downloaded by post code or areas of 1km2 to show mean wind speed across the nation. Just a simple figure (e.g 10mph) per grid square would be ideal so I can associate a colour for every grid to generate a 'heat map' for wind speed.

I've looked into:

https://maps.darksky.net/

Although I don't think that's what I'm after.

This is more what I'm after...http://www.renew-reuse-recycle.com/noabl.pl?go=Go&postcode=NE66+1TL&osx=&osy=&country=gb

Comment: I cant give you a detailed answer just yet but have a look at the [NOAA](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/data-access)  site for a start. they usually have world wide data

Comment: Can the data be in netCDF? May it be daily data from that you calculate the annual average on your own?

Comment: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/10154/sources-of-weather-data/10155 may or may not be helpful.

Comment: @daniel.neumann indeed it can be daily data. So long as I can extract historical data at 1km2 grids then that would be perfect

Comment: @JamesB Historical data: which year(s) exactly? Would it be also OK to get data in a coarser resolution that is interpolated to 1x1 km2? Since you need annual averages, the introduced error might not be that high. Are you doing the work within an academic context (more general: 'non-profil') and do you have an email account at an European academic institution?

Comment: @daniel.neumann Data coverage from 2010 would be adequate. 1x1km would be perfect. The answer would be no to the last two questions. I work for a commercial company and acquiring a dataset like this would help us target the more suited areas in the country to install small 200kw-500kw wind turbines. The data would not be shared in vector/raster form.

Comment: @JamesB  1x1 km is a quite fine resolution. You could apply for data from the (coastDat Database)[http://www.coastdat.de/about_us/index.php.en] (approx 12 x 12 km2). (Dahlgren et al. (2016))[http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/qj.2807/full] presented a regional model run for 2010 (see section 6). ECMWF (ERA-Interim)[http://www.ecmwf.eu/en/research/climate-reanalysis/era-interim] has only 80 x80 km2 resolution (maybe only for academic purpose).

Comment: @JamesB Soon, there will be (ECMWF ERA5)[http://climate.copernicus.eu/climate-reanalysis] data be available. It will be published within the (EU Copernicus Programme)[http://copernicus.eu/]. All Copernicus data (Satellite, Model, In-Situ Measurements) are for free (at least for European citizens). The data will be published within the (Copernicus Climate Service)[http://climate.copernicus.eu/climate-reanalysis].

Comment: @daniel.neumann Great, thank you very much for your help, I'll be on the look out for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Courtesy of Daniel Neumann (See comments)

Soon, there will be (ECMWF ERA5)[climate.copernicus.eu/climate-reanalysis] data be available. It will be published within the (EU Copernicus Programme)[copernicus.eu/]. All Copernicus data (Satellite, Model, In-Situ Measurements) are for free (at least for European citizens). The data will be published within the (Copernicus Climate Service)[climate.copernicus.eu/climate-reanalysis]. – daniel.neumann