# Seeking Meteorological stations data for Europe, especially Denmark?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, meteorology

Where can I find a geospatial data set of meteorological stations of Europe, preferably in point geometry for Denmark?

Comment: are you only interested in the geometry or also at data like wind temperature etc.?

Comment: Yes, geometry with temperature, wind data would also be good.

Comment: I've found some data here at [the European Environment Agency](http://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/air-pollutant-concentrations-at-station). While i am not 100% sure if this is the right answer. but it could be a start. If this is what you are after let me know so i expand the comend

Comment: As I can see this is air pollution concentrations data with lat/long which can be converted to point shapefile. I could not find any temperature or wind data. Anyways thanks for your help.

Comment: @JibranKhan my impression is, that at those stations other paramerters like wind temp. etc are mesaured but i could be wrong.

Comment: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/10154/sources-of-weather-data/10155 may or may not be helpful.