# Seeking current global cloud cover data?

Tags: data-request, weather, noaa

I'm working on a project to check variation of UV index with cloud cover. I'm trying to get the cloud cover data which I'll be using to plot the graph. I've historical data which I got from [MODIS](https://ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/missions-and-measurements/products/cloud/MOD06_L2) (MOD06_L2). But it doesn't has the current(today's) data. The closest date for which they have the data is 4 days back. Does anyone knows of any reliable source where I can get this data  ? It will be better if the source has hourly data for cloud cover.

Comment: You might skim http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/10154/sources-of-weather-data/10155 to see if any of those meet your needs. The "cycle file" data is about as close to realtime as you can get (short of actually going outside <G>)

Comment: As @BarryCarter said, please see my answer at this question. You can find weather data from https://rp5.ru/ 10 min. after recording.

Comment: @juminet I think rp5.ru gets data from the cycle files itself. Are you affiliated with rp5.ru? I think it's best to send users to official sources when possible.

Comment: No I'm not affiliated with rp5.ru at all. I've just found this website and found it useful. And yes, I'd like to know the official sources of data from METAR and SYNOP.