# UK monthly weather data

Tags: weather, uk

Is anyone aware of any monthly UK weather data based on grids, easting nothing, or even postcodes? Any pointers would be very much appreciated.

Comment: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/search?q=uk+weather

Comment: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/10154/sources-of-weather-data/10155 is more generic but may help