# climate station data -not gridded data

Tags: climate

I am look for monthly temperature and precipitation data for various countries. Ideally the data would be for period 1981-2010, but other would also be fine.

I know this site: https://www.metoffice.gov.uk/research/climate/climate-monitoring/land-and-atmosphere/surface-station-records

but it has only temperature-data

edit 8.6.2018:
https://www.dwd.de/DE/leistungen/klimadatenwelt/klimadatenwelt_node.html
has some data, but for period 1961-1990

Comment: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/10154/sources-of-weather-data/10155 may or may not be helpful

Comment: thanks, I did read this post, before asking. Unfortunatley  its not what I am looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found some useful links for station-based data for period 1981-2010:
data for Austria:
https://www.zamg.ac.at/cms/de/klima/informationsportal-klimawandel/daten-download/klimamittel

data for Germany:
https://opendata.dwd.de/climate_environment/CDC/observations_germany/climate/multi_annual/mean_81-10/

data for switzerland:
https://www.meteoswiss.admin.ch/home/climate/swiss-climate-in-detail/climate-normals/climate-diagrams-and-normals--per-station.html?region=Table

data for USA:
https://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/normals/1981-2010/

data for Australia:
http://www.bom.gov.au/jsp/ncc/cdio/cvg/av?p_stn_num=015528&p_prim_element_index=0&p_comp_element_index=0&redraw=null&p_display_type=statistics_summary&normals_years=1981-2010&tablesizebutt=normal

data for Canada:
http://climate.weather.gc.ca/climate_normals/results_1981_2010_e.html?stnID=1641&autofwd=1

Answer (score 1):

The Atmospheric Radiation Measurement (ARM) program has been collecting precipitation, temperature and more for decades. You’ll want other datasets to get global coverage, but ARM data will give you a high level of detail and quality for the areas they cover.

> [ARM focuses on obtaining continuous measurements—supplemented by field campaigns—and providing data products that promote the advancement of climate models. Serving users worldwide, the ARM Data Center collects and archives approximately 20 terabytes of data per month. Datastreams are generally available for download within 48 hours.](https://www.arm.gov/data)