# Where can I find historical rainfall and temperature data for individual weather stations in the US?

Tags: weather, historical

I'm reading a journal paper that uses historical rainfall and temperature data for the United States, starting in 1900. The paper says

> The [National Weather Service Cooperative] COOP Network consists of more than 20,000 sites across the United States and has monthly precipitation observations for the past 100 years

Are these data publicly available? I'm looking for these historical rainfall and temperature data, **for every individual station**, in a machine-readable format that I can use to map stations and their corresponding data to US counties.

I am not looking for forecasts, and it's not clear to me *which* [sources of weather data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/10155/3565) actually have data going back this far. The NOAA pages usually list data starting in 1981.

---

The paper is

> Ramcharan, Rodney. "Inequality and redistribution: evidence from US counties and states, 1890–1930." The Review of Economics and Statistics 92, no. 4 (2010): 729-744.

Unfortunately, the private data provider that compiled these data (Weather Source) no longer offers them. They told me this directly when I contacted them.

Comment: Did you contact the author of the paper? He might still have the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Containing  observations  of  one  or  more of  the  above  elements  at  more than  100,000  stations  that  are  distributed  across  all  continents,  the dataset is  the  world's  largest  collection  of daily  climatological  data. [...] Station  records,  some  of  which extend  back  to  the  19th  century,  are  updated  daily  where  possible  and  are  usually  available  one  to  two days  after  the  date  and  time of  the  observation. [NOAA: GHCN (Global Historical Climatology  Network)-Daily](https://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/cdo/documentation/GHCND_documentation.pdf)

This is from the documentation of the *Daily Summaries*. They provide access via FTP to all available stations and their data that exist. I checked a few stations and found some data going back to e.g. 1964 etc.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this! It looks useful. Hopefully most of the data go back well before 1964, since I need data for 1900-1940, but I'll check it and report back.

Comment: @MichaelA That would be great. Unfortuntaley, one has to look into all files to find out.

Comment: Ah, I see. The Daily Summaries allow you to input dates as far back as 1763, but then you need to search for stations individually (which I'm less than keen to do for 20,000 stations).

Comment: @MichaelA You don't have to do this. Go on the FTP and into the folder *all*.

Comment: @MichaelA You'll find a file for each station including all its data as far back as it exists.

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising. These are the flat files that your [documentation link](ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/cdo/documentation/GHCND_documentation.pdf) refers to, right?

Comment: @MichaelA Have a look at the [README.txt](http://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/ghcn/daily/readme.txt), especially section *III. FORMAT OF DATA FILES (".dly" FILES)*. I found it more useful than the PDF documentation.