# Typical Weather Averages by Lon/Lat

Tags: api, weather, historical

I would like to build a local dataset of monthly averages for rainfall, sunshine hours, temperate (C/F) for all the major cities of the world.

I have all the lon/lat's stored for all the cities I need in SQL, so what is the best way to mine this data?

The links to the monthly Global Historical Climatology Network files seem to be broken, and I wouldn't quite know the best way to parse them.

So say we took 2018 as an example; I just want something like this [image]

I can consume an API if there is a free one; but it also looks like what Weather Underground offers;

https://www.wunderground.com/history/monthly/gb/hounslow/EGLL/date/2018-1

I know its a lot of data I need, but I really need to find a free source for this data ideally, or at worst one which wont cost hundreds of dollars.

Can anyone help?

Comment: There are over a [100 questions on this site tagged weather](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weather), surely your answer is among them?

Comment: I’ve just double checked that list in full - no, no similar questions - happy to stand corrected but I want monthly averages for cities; temperature, mm, sunshine and ranges - I see nothing else similar.

Comment: But wouldn't e.g. daily data be sufficient? You can do the averages.

Comment: For 5 datasets, and for 6700 cities... probably would exceed most API limits or be unworkable. These averages are on many sites so I can’t be the first to need them. I don’t think the processing is realistic - however if daily sources meet the needs then yes...

Comment: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/10154/sources-of-weather-data may or may not be helpful

Answer (score 1):

NOAA is where you should be looking which also has enough historical data and a lot of modalities. They have different options for download. If you are looking for an API, this is a starting point.

https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/webservices/v2

Cheers!