# Open source weather database for predict crop disease?

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, python, agriculture

I have started to work on forecasting models for precision agriculture. My goal is to train a model which uses temperature, relative humidity, and rainfall to predict when late blight (*Phytophthora infestans*) epidemics are not likely to occur. Similar to the [Fry Model or Negative Prognosis Model for potato production](http://ipm.ucanr.edu/DISEASE/DATABASE/potatolateblight.html)

**I am looking for a dataset of weather data linked to crop diseases.**

Comment: What is *weather data for crop disease*? Do you want a dataset linking weather to diseases (to train a model), or just weather. Where? In what format? How much data? Please read [What a good request looks like](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284/how-a-good-data-request-question-should-look-like)

Comment: Please answer my other question and [edit] them into the original question. The better your question is, the likelier you'll get answers. Comments can disappear.

Comment: You can get weather data linked to time and location (eg, http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/10154/sources-of-weather-data/10155), so if you can find when and where crop blights occur, you could "join" the two datasets.