# Where can I get historical data on monsoon or sea wind?

Tags: geospatial

I am trying to find some GIS historical data on [monsoon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monsoon).

I have tried a few places which give data on the weather forecast, temperature, and rainfall. But, I was thinking if there is a better data source that could potentially measure the path of monsoon.

I think the historical data on sea wind (speed and directions) might be helpful as well.

Also, I would appreciate you could suggest me better proxies (and source) that I could use to study the monsoon.

Comment: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/10154/sources-of-weather-data/10155 doesn't answer your question, but you may want to take a look at it anyway.

Comment: If you can find a good definition of "monsoon," perhaps you can extract monsoon data from the existing weather/climate data that Barry linked to. For example, Wikipedia says that the African monsoon ranges from about June 22 through October. So you could filter weather data for that location to that date range. Or maybe you can find a dataset of monsoon start and end dates. [This map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:India_southwest_summer_monsoon_onset_map_en.svg) shows arrival dates of the Indian summer monsoon, which implies that that data exists somewhere.

Comment: The India Meteorological Department has this resource for monsoon start dates: http://www.imd.gov.in/pages/monsoon_main.php