# Looking for an API with average min / max temperatures per month for every country

Tags: api, weather

I cannot find any open api data for the average minimum and maximum temperature on a monthly basis per country.

An example:

Country=Netherlands
Month=October
Min=5
Max=13

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Start here: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/10154/sources-of-weather-data