# Trouble finding GIS annual climate data for Spain

Tags: data-request, geospatial, climate

I'm trying to get annual mean temperature and annual precipitation for Spain by province. I've tried going through NOAA, AEMET, and a few other resources but I'm having a hard time getting data in a format I can understand or utilize.

AEMET keeps giving me tar.gz files filled with a file that has no type. I haven't had any luck getting that into anything usable and don't even know if its supposed to be a shapefile, an .e00 or what.

I don't necessarily need the data in a GIS format. I just want something that I can easily convert or aggregate to a by province format which I could then join to a province shapefile I have.

I saw this community linked in a GIS stackExchange answer and am hoping it can help me with this.

Comment: I'm guessing you've looked at http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/10154 but just in case you haven't.

Comment: Can you provide direct links to some examples of the data you've already downloaded? Maybe someone can help you parse the AEMET dataset.