# Daily precipitation data (mm)

Tags: data-request

I am looking for a precipitation data (mm). I found one in published paper, I contacted the author but unfortunately, I revive no answer. I hope someone can help me with this data. Where can I find it, or similar to it?

The daily precipitation data (mm) for the period January 1,1990 to December 31,2006,measured from four meteorological stations in the four municipalities, one station for each municipality of Akershus County in southern Norway.

Comment: Hi @Maryam, try searching this site for posts pertaining to precipitation data sources: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/search?q=precipitation.  Posts [like this one](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/10154/7031) are a good start.