# Indian monthly climate data

Tags: data-request, india, climate

Where can I find Indian district-wise monthly climate data indicators like temperature and humidity, which are open-source?

Also, it would be really helpful if somebody describes the procedure in which the above data can be downloaded.

Comment: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/10154/sources-of-weather-data/10155 might help

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[**India Climatological Data**](https://library.noaa.gov/Collections/Digital-Docs/Foreign-Climate-Data/India-Climate-Data)

The publications shown below contains climatological and other geophysical data for India. The description shows the dates of coverage for each publication, the parameters you can find in the data, and a list of the volumes that the Library holds with links to the years for which images are available.

```
India weather review. Annual summary (1891-1927)
India weather review. Annual summary. Part A, Summary of weather with tables. (1928-1966)
India weather review. Annual summary. Part B, Snowfall (1928-1970)
India weather review. Annual summary. Part C, Storms and depressions (1928-1970)
Monthly weather review (Calcutta, India) (1891-1920)
Rainfall of India for ... (1891-1914)
Daily rainfall of India for ... (1915-1955)
Monthly weather report for ... (1823-1932)
India weather review, ... monthly weather report (133-1969)
```