# Seeking traffic and weather datasets

Tags: data-request, weather, traffic

I am looking for a dataset of traffic flow and its corresponding weather data, such as rain and temperature, of the same location. I am studying the effect of weather variables on traffic, preferably inside cities not on highways.

P.S. I could find traffic data of some locations without the corresponding weather, and vice versa. What I need is both data of the same location.

Comment: I found this dataset: https://www.d.umn.edu/~tkwon/TMCdata/TMCarchive.html which is about Twin Cities highways and you can find the corresponding weather data at http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/request/download.phtml?network=MN_ASOS

However, these data are captured on highways where the effect of weather on traffic is not very clear. I need data like this for roads inside cities where weather stations are close to these roads.

Comment: What location are you looking for data on? Specific to a latitude/longitude? City-wide? Country-wide? Worldwide?

Comment: No specific location. Any traffic data captured inside a city can work as long as they are consistent with the corresponding weather data of the same location.

Comment: for weather data, see: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/10154/11218

Answer (score 0):

I use visual crossing for weather data ([www.visualcrossing.com](http://www.visualcrossing.com)). I can specify latitude and longitude for weather data. It is a consistent data set for historical and forecast that I use in AI/ML applications through their webservices API. It contains all the key weather data I need for my applications including solar radiation.

For historical traffic by location I use [www.tomtom.com](http://www.tomtom.com) (webservices API). If you need real-time just use the google API for traffic.