# Open data that changes daily for every county in the United States

Tags: usa, data.gov, crime, county

Is there any open data that changes daily for every county in the United States? I'm working on a project that involves finding patterns in data across counties. I've had a difficult time finding daily weather data. Is there crime data available every day in every county? Any government data? Financial?

Comment: COVID-19 data might do this: https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19 and https://github.com/datasets/covid-19 For weather data, http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/10154/sources-of-weather-data/10155 might help, but getting daily data and county data might be difficult

Answer (score 1):

Climate.gov provides a way to get daily weather data by zip code https://www.climate.gov/maps-data/dataset/past-weather-zip-code-data-table.

Comment: Thank you @steve_in_the_22201, the issue there is it will take a tremendous amount of time to get data on all >3k counties in the US. I have to search, add to cart, check out, wait for the email, then download for each county.

Comment: There is a service here https://openweathermap.org/price#history with an API that allows free access to current info, and costs money to buy the historical dump.