# Wind Speed and Direction Datasets

Tags: data-request, data.gov, releasing-data, large-datasets

I am trying to find historical (e.g., one year) wind speed and wind direction datasets for different suburbs in Sydney/Greater Sydney in CSV format. I tried different platforms for it but could not find it. If it is not possible to get free of charge, any other city's dataset including different station locations could also be acceptable.

Any help in this regard is much appreciated.

Comment: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/10154/sources-of-weather-data/ might be a starting point

Comment: Thank you. I checked the links provided in the answer you shared. However, it looks difficult to find a dataset that matches my requirements.